# How to store SparkR result into an R object?

Tags: r, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

Still new to the world of Azure Databricks, the use of SparkR remains very obscure to me, even for very simple tasks...

It took me a very long time to find how to count distinct values, and I'm not sure it's the right way to go :

```
library(SparkR)
sparkR.session()

DW <- sql("select * from db.mytable")
nb.var <- head(summarize(DW, n_distinct(DW$VAR)))
```

I thought I found, but nb.per is not an object, but still a dataframe...

```
class(nb.per)
[1] "data.frame"
```

I tried :

```
nb.per <- as.numeric(head(summarize(DW, n_distinct(DW$PERIODE))))
```

It seems ok, but I'm pretty sure there is a better way to achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are anyway using Spark SQL, a very simple approach would be to do like this:
 `` nb.per <- `[[`(SparkR::collect(SparkR::sql("select count(distinct VAR) from db.mytable")), 1) ``.
And using SparkR APIs like:

```
DW <- SparkR::tableToDF("db.mytable")
nb.per <- `[[`(SparkR::collect(SparkR::agg(DW, SparkR::countDistinct(SparkR::column("VAR")))), 1)
```

Comment: Seems great to me ! But what does ````'[['```` mean for, please ??

Comment: It is the usual subset operator as provided in `base`, just like we subset an element from a list or vector: 
# x <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = c("e")) # in this case, x$a, x[["a"]], and \`[[\`(x, "a") are equivalent.
Please note the enclosing backticks. You may find more details by doing " ?\`[[\` "

Comment: Oooh ok thank you, I did not know this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `SparkR::sql` function returns a SparkDataFrame.

In order to use this in R as an R data.frame, you can simply coerce it:

```
 as.data.frame(sql("select * from db.mytable"))
```

Comment: On very (very) large table, won't I lose in performance ? I wanted to work with SparkR, which seems the most efficient for working on Hive tables ?

Comment: Yes, but the question literally asks how to store the result into an R object, and I think I've answered that.

Comment: You are right. Maybe I am lost because I have to rewrite my R data.table script on Databricks. Are there any SparkR objects to store a numeric value ?

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question about that. Perhaps include a portion of the R dataframe code and show any attempts that you've made yourself. You might also want to look into the `sparklyr` package.